# Pygame sprites timer

Tags: python, pygame

I need to make a list of sprites, each of which should have some kind of a timer, so it can perform an action on its own ( like shooting every 10 sec for example). But they will be created and added new ones at a different time, so each of them should has its own timer.
I know how to make list of sprites, but I don't know how to attach a timer to each of them or something like that. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the timer as an attribute of the sprites:

```
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.timer = pygame.Clock()
        # ...
    # ...
```

Or (make sure there is no member already called `timer`):

```
for sprite in sprites:
    sprite.timer = pygame.Clock()
```

Or you could change your list into a list of tuples, containing a sprite and a timer:

```
sprites = [(sprite, pygame.Clock()) for sprite in sprites]
```

This will make a list with the format:

```
[(sprite, timer), (sprite, timer), ...]
```

You can then access the sprite and timer:

```
sprite = sprites[0][0]  # first sprite
timer = sprites[0][1]  # first timer
```

Or:

```
sprite, timer = sprites[0]  # first pair
```

You could also have a dictionary of `{sprite: timer}`, and then access the timer for a sprite with `sprite_to_timer[sprite]`.

*Note: Replace `pygame.Clock` by what ever timer you want to use*